# Homemade Corn Flour

Tags: flour, corn, grinding

I have a *wondermill* which I use for grinding wheat (I think it grinds it by blowing it through blades of something). Is there is some way for me to dry out frozen corn kernels so that I can send them through the grinder and come out with flour?

If I can grind dry corn somehow, is this something that'd risk breaking the machine? Please don't recommend a method if it's risky!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you could, what you get wouldn't be your standard corn meal.

There are a few different varieties of corn, and what you get frozen would be 'sweet corn'.  Corn meal and corn masa are made from either 'flour corn', 'dent corn' (aka 'field corn') or 'flint corn',  all of which are lower sugar, higher starch, and allowed to dry in the field.

You'd have better luck trying to grind popcorn into flour.  (which is yet another variety of corn, but has a harder outer husk that allows it to pop)

You might be able to find suitable corn for grinding in latin markets (as it's used to make masa for tortillas), or in feed stores (as it's used for animal feed).

Comment: Why would sweet corn not work as well? Do sugars and starches have an effect on grinders?

Comment: Sugar is good at gooing up blades. I use a screw grinder wherw that shouldn't be a problem, but the high speed spinners with hundredes of cutting blades are not going to like material build up on what should be *sharp* edges.

Answer (score 2):

Corn is harder than wheat. I use a corn mill to grind corn.
That said, question 4 [here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000CPJKWC) makes the claim that your mill will grind dried corn nicely. I'd start with just a quarter cup or so to see what happens, then work my way up if all seems well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the wondermill website has a link to [willitgrind](http://willitgrind.com/) which tells in detail what my grinder can, and cannot grind.